# Auto scale up web role in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

When working on scaling scenarios, there is a lot of info on how to scale out automatically a web role in Microsoft Azure.

I've been looking for info on how to scale up (increase instance size) a web role automatically with no luck.

Does anybody know if is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 3):

I do not remember if there ever was any tool or portal functionality to do that and change the size.

[VM size for the cloud service is defined by the csdef file](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-model-and-package/). Csdef file is in the cloud service package file - so, for that, the autoscaling process should automate the re-upload of the package file. I suppose that re-uploading the file with the package would start the deployment from a scratch. And the amount of instances are implemented in the cscsfg file that should be uploaded as a file beside the package.

So, i believe, it may not be built because it can not be implemented in such manner that it can be very stable and/or fast for everyone (i mean, to autoscale something that requires the package file to redeployed likely means to have that not working for a time being).